# Tokbox Youtube Broadcast issue

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, broadcast, tokbox

I am using [tokbox](https://tokbox.com/) js for stream sharing and also using youtube API for RTMP broadcast. After successful broadcast and bind it will always display a blank screen on youtube. No error in console and the stream rate is healthy.

```
var streamResource ={ "snippet": { "title": ajaxLoginInstance.meetingSubject, "isDefaultStream":false }, "cdn":{ //"format":'1080p', "frameRate":'30fps', "resolution":'480p', "ingestionType":'rtmp' } };
```

Comment: I had also a discussion with tokbox support and they are saying that there is no wrong in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using custom layout then you have to add style-sheet to it. Sometimes streams were there but they are not in viewport so display a blank screen. I hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, I did the same and now stream are visible on youtube. Thanks!

Comment: Also, Tokbox provides predefined layouts. Please check by below URL: